# Why is my sympy Simult eqn calc not working

Tags: python, sympy

I have a simultaneous equation calculator that takes in a lst which contains the strings of the two equations and is supposed to output the solutions to X and Y. Here is the code for it.

```
x, y = symbols('x,y')
transformations=(standard_transformations + (implicit_multiplication_application,))
eqs_sympy = [Eq(parse_expr(e.split('=')[0], transformations=transformations),
             parse_expr(e.split('=')[1], transformations=transformations))
             for e in final_lst]
sol = solve(eqs_sympy)
```

An example of final_lst : ["5x^2 + 1y^5 = 12", "5x^3 + 18y^2 = 42"] (Replace ^ with **)
However, sol just outputs a blank list, why is this so?

Comment: This is a very complicated way of explaining the input that you pass to solve. Remove all of the parsing and present simple code that shows the input to solve and demonstrates the behaviour you are asking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These highly nonlinear equations are too high of order for SymPy to give an explicit solution. You can get a numerical solution, however, if you have a good initial guess for the solution. You can get a reasonable guess by graphing the equations or by solving the related equations that don't have the highest powered terms. Use `nsolve` (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61233543/how-can-i-solve-a-simultaneous-equation-in-python-using-sympy?rq=1)). Here is one of the 3 roots:

```
>>> from sympy import nsolve
>>> tuple(nsolve(eqs,(x,y),(-1,1)))
(-0.731937744431011, 1.56277202986898)
```

Comment: sorry im quite new to sympy but how do i do this?

Comment: I added some examples to the answer.

Comment: Do you know what polynomial does it function until? Like can it solve up till quadratic, cubic etc.